# android expandableListView - add items to a specific group at run time

Tags: android, cursor, adapter, expandablelistview

i met a problem , i have a expandableListView has 5 groups

if i wanna add some items to the second group , and update the expandableListView at run time,

could someone teach me how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update the cursor/adapter generating the ExpandableListView and automatically the view will be regenerated

Comment: i did update the adapter , but the expandablelistView didn't update.......was there something i forgot?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using BaseExpandableListAdapter then you can get getChildView (...) at run time where you can add anything you want .if still you face any problem come with more detail what you want to do ,